# How to avoid StackOverflow on bidirectional relationship in hibernate/jpa?

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm thinking how to avoid StackOverflow on my query. I need bidirectional relationship because once I will ask for `Happening` to get the `Place` of that, and the other way I will ask for `Place` to get `Happenings` there. 
But now when I ask for `Happening` it throws me Stack overflow because of that `Place` contains `Set` of `Happenings`. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Happening {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    private Place place;
}
public class Place {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "place")
    private Set<Happening> happenings;
}
```

Using JPA repository I ask for

```
public Happening getHappening(Long id) {
    return happeningRepository.findById(id).get();
}
```

**Error**

```
Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.proj.happening.Models.Happening[&quot;place&quot;]-&gt;com.proj.happening.Models.Place
```

**EDIT**

I try to use solutions from here: [https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion][1]
but ok I don't have recursion when I call for Happening because I lost `Set<Happening> happenings;` data, but when I want to call from the other side and get Place I lost `Set<Happening> happenings;` too. That is not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: To tell you what you are doing "wrong", don't you think it would be good to post code of what you are actually doing? and also the stack trace ?

Comment: I add you a code and that what Exception I get

Comment: Presuming you're using Jackson, you'll want `@JsonIdentityInfo`.

Comment: What JSON library are you using?

Comment: Jackson I add `@JsonManagedReference` on `private Place place;` and `@JsonBackReference
    private Set<Happening> happenings;` but it help only in way when I ask for Happening but when I ask for Place it didn't show me any set of heppenings (no property)

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Comment: So the problem is nothing to do with JPA, and everything to do with JSON. Hence retag it

Comment: @BillyFrost but when I debug code I have StackOverflow on objects

Comment: On JSON (Jackson) calls, which is not JPA API calls. And why haven't you posted the stack trace? JSON serialisation is totally nothing to do with the JPA API.

Comment: @BillyFrost what do you want me to stack trace? Recursive hibernate query? or Recursive Json Parse and then StackOverflow exception?

Comment: A stackoverflow has a stack trace! Just showing it shows people the method calls causing the problem. Step 1 in debugging